# Chrome install failed on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, google-chrome

I have tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and then `sudo apt-get update`

but I still have the same dependency problems:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:i386:
google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on xdg-utils
```

And idea how to fix it?

BTW, when I use `sudo apt-get install -f`, I got an output:

```
After this operation, 119 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

which seems to remove the files.

Comment: The version in the repositories is out of date. It is best to download the .deb from the official Google chrome site: installing that deb also adds the Google repository, which will keep it up to date.

Comment: hi mik: i do download from the official site, which i believe is the latest version.@Mik

Comment: @Mik I can confirm the problem:

 - fresh installation of 12.04.1 done today in 64 bit version
 - downloaded chrome 32 bit deb package at www.google.com/chrome/
 - double clicking on the deb file or launching `dpkg - i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` fails with the error `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:i386:
google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on xdg-utils` descibed originally

Comment: @maximd and Nathan I should try installing the 64 bit .deb of Chrome if you are running a 64 bit system.

Comment: @Mik I am running a 32-bit system, I am quite sure on that.

Answer (score 3):

As [maximd's comment](https://askubuntu.com/users/59603/maximd) under your question has shown, the same error as yours occurs when trying to install 32 bit Chrome under a 64 bit Ubuntu system. These `i386`  error message always occurs when it is an architecture problem. In contrast, I successfully installed the same 32 bit deb on a 32 bit system today, so the issue is not due to a bad version of Chrome.

The architecture error is well known, as documented [in a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/346775/errors-on-attempting-to-install-32-bit-chrome-in-64-bit-ubuntu) at Superuser where similar dependency issues are discussed. On account of [Ubuntu's multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) feature (which enables the user to install 32 bit packages on 64 bit systems) these sorts of errors don't occur very regularly now, but are still possible. Sometimes it is still necessary to use the 64 bit version of the package.

There is **no** point in forcing the installation with something like `sudo dpkg -i --force /location/of/deb`, as that will not solve the dependency issues, so I should just remove the partial installation of Chrome with `sudo apt-get install -f` and install the 64 bit deb from the Google Chrome site with `gdebi` or `Software Center`, which will resolve the dependencies as well.

Comment: to be honest I did not try 64 bit version of Chrome because - from what I remember - the 64 bit version does not (cannot?) integrate flash (I mean, the flash version bundled with Chrome). Though I just stumbled upon this [superuser.com question about "Flash player not present in Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bits"](http://superuser.com/questions/425970/flash-player-not-present-in-chrome-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bits) and it seems that the solution for flash support in chrome 64 bit is to install flash through the ubuntu repositories/software center

Comment: I found this post by google and It is useful for me :)

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by [bug #992797](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-utils/+bug/992797).

It's not due to the version number but the lack of Multi-Arch support in the `xdg-utils` package. I was able to successfully install Chrome without `--force-depends` by adding `Multi-Arch: foreign` to the `DEBIAN/control` file for `xdg-utils` and rebuilding that package with dpkg-deb, but of course this still leaves `apt-get dist-upgrade` broken because the repositories have a broken version.

Update: If you add an epoch to the version, it will fix apt-get. So the full workaround is:

```
apt-get download xdg-utils
dpkg-deb -R xdg-utils*.deb xdg-utils
patch xdg-utils/DEBIAN/control # (paste in the patch below)
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build xdg-utils xdg-utils-hacked.deb
sudo dpkg -i xdg-utils-hacked.deb
```

patch:

```
--- xdg-utils.orig/DEBIAN/control   2011-10-04 00:49:41.000000000 -0400
+++ xdg-utils/DEBIAN/control    2012-11-30 16:24:15.365170233 -0500
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 Package: xdg-utils
-Version: 1.1.0~rc1-2ubuntu6
+Version: 1:1.1.0~rc1-2ubuntu6
 Architecture: all
+Multi-Arch: foreign
 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
 Installed-Size: 316
 Recommends: libfile-mimeinfo-perl, x11-utils, x11-xserver-utils
```

Comment: Don't use an epoch like that or you won't ever get updates for xdg-utils.

Comment: Agree. You should tell your package management to hold that specific version instead. +1 for pointing+commenting at bug report, though.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but here is my guess:
chrome depends on `xdg-utils >= 1.0.2`, but you have installed `1.1.0~rc1-2ubuntu6` (at least I have this on my linux mint 13 64 bit).

Somewhere there is a misunderstanding that leads apt to believe your 1.1.0 rc1 version is earlier than 1.0.2, thus not satisfying the dependency.

If I'm right the problem will disappear as soon as xdg-utils will have a final version number. In the meanwhile I personally enjoy a flawlessly running Chrome installed with `dpkg -i --force-depend`.

Comment: I don't believe in "misunderstandings" in apt for a simple version number comparison. If that would be the case a lot more would be broken.